# I have a problem with 'source' in Makefile not with virtualenv

Tags: docker, makefile, virtualenv

I am using virtualenv as virtual environment for my project. I activated my virtualenv and I am working in this environment. After that, I run this command in cmd of windows: `make build_image` but I got an error bellow:

```
source "../deployment/.env" && bash deployment/deploy.sh build
'source' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
make: *** [Makefile:9: build_image] Error 1
```

File Makefile:

```
SHELL=/bin/bash

ENV_FILE="./deployment/.env"

feast_apply:
    source ${ENV_FILE} && bash scripts/feast_helper.sh apply

build_image:
    source ${ENV_FILE} && bash deployment/deploy.sh build

build_push_image:
    source ${ENV_FILE} && bash deployment/deploy.sh build_push

deploy_dags:
    source ${ENV_FILE} && bash deployment/deploy.sh dags

deploy_feature_repo:
    source ${ENV_FILE} && bash deployment/deploy.sh feature_repo
```

Comment: How did you install Make? The version from MSYS2 uses `sh` as shell, not CMD, so it shouldn't have this issue.

Comment: I followed this tutorial to install Make: https://bobbyhadz.com/blog/make-is-not-recognized-as-internal-or-external-command. Make version: ```GNU Make 4.4.1
Built for Windows32
Copyright (C) 1988-2023 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <https://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.```

Comment: My recommendation would be to uninstall this version and reinstall from MSYS2: https://stackoverflow.com/q/30069830/2752075

Comment: I followed your recommendation and I also set C:/msys64/ucrt64/bin in Path but when I open cmd and run `make --version`. I got an error message:  ```'make' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.``` I don't understand :(

Comment: `make` installs to `C:/msys64/usr/bin` I think?

Comment: Oh my mistake for not checking where make is located. Thank you for your help on this issue.